# I want to create a dynamic and interactive donut chart (javascript & css )

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, sql

These diagrams should get data from "MYSQL-DB" and update it's data in live accordingly, without refreshing the page.
I do not have much experience in this field, this is one of my first personal front-end projects and I would much appreciate some assistance with the subject.

link for illustrate images
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TOpQ.jpg

the demo below is not displayed well, which is why I included an "SCSS" file (link below) that should be inserted in the project as an additive.
https://textuploader.com/tdbdd

---

```
@keyframes bake-pie {
  from {
transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  background: #EEE;
}
main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.pieID {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.pie {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.pie::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.pie::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 220px auto;
  
}
.slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  animation: bake-pie 1s;
}
.slice span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}
.legend {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #DDD,
          2px 2px 0 #BBB;
}
.legend li {
  width: 110px;
  height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  border-left: 1.25em solid black;
}
.legend em {
  font-style: normal;
}
.legend span {
  float: right;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #DDD;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}


function sliceSize(dataNum, dataTotal) {
    return (dataNum / dataTotal) * 360;
  }
  function addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color) {
    $(pieElement).append("<div class='slice "+sliceID+"'><span></span></div>");
    var offset = offset - 1;
    var sizeRotation = -179 + sliceSize;


    $("."+sliceID).css({
      "transform": "rotate("+offset+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)"
    });
    $("."+sliceID+" span").css({
      "transform"       : "rotate("+sizeRotation+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)",
      "background-color": color
    });
  }
  
  function iterateSlices(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, dataCount, sliceCount, color) {
    var sliceID = "s"+dataCount+"-"+sliceCount;
    var maxSize = 179;
    if(sliceSize<=maxSize) {
      addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
    } else {
      addSlice(maxSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
      iterateSlices(sliceSize-maxSize, pieElement, offset+maxSize, dataCount, sliceCount+1, color);
    }
  }
  function createPie(dataElement, pieElement) {
    var listData = [];
    $(dataElement+" span").each(function() {
      listData.push(Number($(this).html()));
    });
    var listTotal = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
      listTotal += listData[i];
    }
    var offset = 0;
    var color = [ 
      "#4c1180", 
      "#17b2bd", 
      "#006666",
    ];
    for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
      var size = sliceSize(listData[i], listTotal);
      iterateSlices(size, pieElement, offset, i, 0, color[i]);
      $(dataElement+" li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").css("border-color", color[i]);
      offset += size;
    }
  }
  createPie(".pieID.legend", ".pieID.pie");





@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
@-webkit-keyframes bake-pie {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes bake-pie {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.pieID {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pie {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 0.2rem solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .2rem #fff,
            0 0 .2rem #fff,
            0 0 2rem #0D43E3,
            0 0 0.8rem #0D43E3,
            0 0 2.8rem #0D43E3,
            inset 0 0 1.3rem #0D43E3; 
            border-radius: 50%; 
}

.pie::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.pie::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 220px auto;
}    
.slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  -webkit-animation: bake-pie 1s;
          animation: bake-pie 1s;
}

.slice span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}

.legend {
  /*position: relative; right: 50%;*/ 
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 0%;
  background: rgb(14, 2, 68);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0.2rem solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .2rem #fff,
 **strong text**               0 0 .2rem #fff,
            0 0 2rem #0D43E3,
            0 0 0.8rem #0D43E3,
            0 0 2.8rem #0D43E3,
            inset 0 0 1.3rem #0D43E3; 
}

.legend li {
  width: 110px;
  height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  border-left: 1.25em solid black;
}

.legend em {
  font-style: normal;
}

.legend span {
  float: left;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #DDD;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=donutTotal.css.map */
```

```html
<ul class="pieID legend">
              <li>
                <em>south</em>
                <span>192</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <em>north</em> 
                <span>192</span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <em>center</em>
                <span>192</span>
              </li>
            </ul> 
            <div class="pieID pie">
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch api method to get the data from database and store that data in an arrya , later use that array to dynamically print the values in the list using loop

```
    let data
    
      async function fetchText() {
        let response = await fetch('/ourUrl');
        let dataget = await response.text();
        data= dataget;
    }

//displaying your data 
  function dispay(data)
{

  for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
      let loopdata="<li>
                <em>data.value</em>
                <span>data.value</span>
              </li>"
    }

return loopdata;

}
```